# Flex items are not aligned side by side (i.e. spaced out)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Okay using flex to align the image (purple) and the content (yellow) side by side. However I am getting extra space between and is throwing off the image to the right.

See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpQBh.jpg

It's supposed to be:

- image should be inside the blue div next to the yellow div
- the yellow    div should be 60% width  (These are flex items)

*I've checked padding and margin, however it hasn't worked for me. Any ideas?*

Here is the html

```
<div class="sec-1">
    <h2>Introducing 'Keeva' world's smartest assistant.</h2>
    <div class="flex-box">
        <div>
            <p class="sales-copy">Keeva smartphone app helps you organize your work schedule, meetings, project deadlines and much more.</p>
                        <!-- Download Buttons -->
                    <img class="download-btns" src="img/playstore-1.png">
                    <img class="download-btns" src="img/iphone-1.png">
        </div>
        <!-- Phone 0 image -->
        <img class="phone-img" src="img/iphone-cut.png" alt="phone image">          
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 599px) {
    .sec-1 h2 {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        background-color: green;
    }

    .sec-1 p {
        font-size: 1.1em;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .sec-1 .phone-img {
        position: relative;
        top: 10%;
        left: 30%;
        background-color: purple;

    } 
    .download-btns {
        position: relative;
        right: 25%;
        background-color: orange;
    }

    .sec-1 .sales-copy {
        width: 50%;
    }


    .flex-box {
        display: flex;
           justify-content: flex-end;

    }

}
```

Comment: Here's an unfinished fiddle to play with. Adjust button img sizes as they're currently set to stretch to 100% of container width/height. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/u3pth5zs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `display: flex` makes its immediate descendants flex items, it is only the `div` that wraps the the `p`/`img` that becomes one.

So to make this work, and since `img` doesn't behave normal when being flex items, move that `div` wrapper to the `img` and it will flow as intended.

I also changed `width: 50%` to `flex-basis: 60%` so the *yellow* element becomes 60%, and added `flex-grow: 1` to the `div` wrapper, so it takes the remaining space.

---

*Updated based on a comment*

Changed to an outer and an inner Flexbox wrapper, so the buttons are located below the *yellow* element and the image to the right

```css
.sec-1 h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: green;
}

.sec-1 p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sec-1 .phone-img {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 30%;
  background-color: purple;
}

.flex-box-outer {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-box-outer > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.flex-box-inner {
  flex-basis: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sec-1">
  <h2>Introducing 'Keeva' world's smartest assistant.</h2>
  <div class="flex-box-outer">  
    <div class="flex-box-inner">
      <p class="sales-copy">Keeva smartphone app helps you organize your work schedule, meetings, project deadlines and much more.</p>
    <!-- Download Buttons -->
      <div>
        <img class="download-btns" src="http://placehold.it/100x50/?text=playstore">
        <img class="download-btns" src="http://placehold.it/100x50/?text=iphone">
      </div>
    </div>
    
  <!-- Phone 0 image -->
    <div>
      <img class="phone-img" src="http://placehold.it/100x50/?text=iphone cut" alt="phone image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay this is pretty close to what is required, however the download buttons should be below the content. Here is a screenshot of what I wanted: http://imgur.com/a/KWf6L

Comment: @Shaz Updated..better ?

Comment: Yes. It works! Thanks. Just one thing: what does .flex-box-outer > div expression mean? '>'

Comment: @Shaz The child selector `>` in `.flex-box-outer > div` means to only target the immediate `div`, so, in this case, not the `div` in `flex-box-inner` get the same rule applied